# How to sync same audio on multiple iphones that are connected in same network in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, synchronization, wifi, audio-streaming

How to sync same audio on multiple iphones that are connected in same network in Swift? i want to play one audio from local storage and play in all other iPhones that connected in same network. Anyone have idea about this then please help me.I appreciate if anyone give answer or any hint. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

One approach:

load the file on all the iPhones and make sure the players are ready to play (enough buffering). Then you can make them start all together at a fixed time (example: if all buffers are ready at 15:03:10, you can ask the devices to start playing from 15:03:13) or you can have a master phone that sends a play command to all slaves after it knows they are ready.

All of this assuming that all iPhones are sync on the same NTP server (which is often the case).

Comment: but @Mikael, How to create server as host and load audio file on server? so, other clients can easily load that audio file on their device and play that audio.